# rails activeadmin select input gives wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, has-many-through

message.rb

```
  has_many :message_users
  has_many :users, through: :message_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_users
```

in activeadmin form

```
permit_params :description,:file, message_user_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :_destroy]

form do |f|
f.inputs "Message" do
  f.input :description
  f.input :file
end

f.has_many :message_users do |message_user|
  message_user.inputs "" do
    message_user.input :user_id, :as => :select,  collection: User.all.map {|u| [  "#{u.name} #{u.phone}", u.id] }
  end
end

f.actions
```

It gives an error message_user.input :user_id line that ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

I cant understand why it gives this error and how to fix it

Comment: One thing I noticed (not sure if that's causing the issue), is in the ```permit_params``` you have ```message_user_attributes```, I think it should be ```message_users_attributes```, because you have ```has_many``` associations.

Answer (score 0):

at first glance, I think the issue might be `message_user.inputs "" do`

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Messages" do
      f.inputs do
        f.input :description
        f.input :file
        f.inputs do
          f.has_many :message_users do |message_user|
            message_user.input :user_id, as: :select, collection: User.all.map { |u| [  "#{u.name} #{u.phone}", u.id] }
          end
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add nested loop you can write it like this

```
f.has_many : message_users, new_record: true do | message_user |
  message_user.input : user_id , as: :select, collection: User.all.map { |u| [  "#{u.name} #{u.phone}", u.id] }
end
```